# add another class to a scrolling js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, codepen

I'm very new to javascript and have no clue on how to add this myself.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = $(this).attr('href'),
      offset = $(target).offset().top - 70;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: offset
    }, 500);
  });
$('.scroll ul li').click(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var prev = $(this).parent().find('.active');
  prev.removeClass('active');
  if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

that's the scrolling code I'm using and it works great for my navbar!

but I just added this button

```
  <a href="#about" class="btn btn-circle page-scroll">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
```

how do I make it so that the script also works with that button in the same way?
http://codepen.io/sbxn14/pen/egmKRr <-- my codepen that contains this site.

I hope someone can help me.

**EDIT:**
While I'm adding it. is it possible to make it so that the active link on the navbar switches if I manually scroll through the page? I've been looking on google on this but haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

To get your button to scroll like the links in your navbar, all you have to do is add the new class to the click handler.

Instead of:

`$('.nav a').on('click', function(e) {`

You simply add the new class to the click handler as such:

`$('.nav a, .page-scroll').on('click', function(e) {`

Alternatively, you could do it like:

`$('.nav a').add('.page-scroll').on('click', function(e) {`

You can also get the navbar to highlight the newly-visible area by adding the `.active` class to the corresponding navbar segment when the button is clicked, as follows:

```
$('.page-scroll').click(function(e) {
   $('.navbar-nav li:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
});
```

Here's an [updated pen](http://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/dNPLaq) showcasing both the button scrolling to the `About` section, and changing the highlighted part of the navbar.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: thank you! but the second part, the active part doesnt work.

Comment: @Chaoss1848 -- I think I see what you mean; While stating the new section is active in the header, I forgot to say that the *current* section is no longer active. This is done by using `$('.navbar-nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');` before adding the new `.action` class on the click. I've updated the pen to correct this, and showcase what should now be the intended behaviour :)